# Defining more than one variable in a vb2005 for loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

Is it possible to define two variables in a vb2005 For loop in a similar way that jscript does it?

the javascript example is

```
for(i=0,l=0;i<20;i++){}
```

Comment: :)
another sign of the upcoming apocalypse, people are referring to features of javascript when this has existed since the epoch - 12/31/1969

Comment: Perhaps.

but it defined what it was i was trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no equivalent syntax in VB.Net.  The for loop declaration can only contain a single variable.

For Loop Syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx